# Invalid syntax trying to create inline python object

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to create a small inline object that uses a lambda function but I keep getting a SyntaxError for this line. The syntax as far as I can tell is correct

```
  mock_popen.return_value = type('obj', (object,), {'communicate' : lambda :'hello','world'})
```

---

**UPDATE:**

In case anyone else is trying to create a module object like this ... *don't*. The code below is a much cleaner and more elegant way of solving the problem.

```
    mock_popen = MagicMock()
    mock_popen.return_value = mock_popen
    mock_popen.communicate.return_value = ('hello','world')
```

Comment: `'hello','world'` => `('hello','world')` you have to explicitly contain both those strings in a tuple.

Comment: Why are you using `type` like this instead of just working with the default `return_value` mock? The mock API is much more convenient for this than messing with `type`.

Comment: @user2357112 Added an update to the question. A little more reading helped. Appreciate it, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the two colons in the last expression; the Python parser doesn't parse the lambda colon followed by the comma-separated list.  There's an visual ambiguity about whether that's a parameter-list comma or a dictionary comma.

Put the two parameters in parentheses, and you should be okay:

```
{'communicate' : lambda :('hello','world')}
```

Output (changing your assignment, since the ID isn't defined):

```
>>> type('obj', (object,), {'communicate' : lambda :('hello','world')})
<class '__main__.obj'>
```

Comment: I get this when I try that `TypeError: unbound method <lambda>() must be called with obj instance as first argument (got nothing instead)`

Comment: @cjds try using "lambda x:" I think your error means it tried to pass in a value to the lambda

Comment: @chbhb55 Yeah. that worked. Was trying to pass the module object to it and I didin't pay attention

Answer (score 1):

Not quite.

```
>>> lambda: 'hello', 'world'
(<function <lambda> at 0x7fc13d86e758>, 'world')
>>> lambda: ('hello', 'world')
<function <lambda> at 0x7fc13d86e7d0>
```

Note the subtle difference in both the input and output.

Comment: I get this when I try that `TypeError: unbound method <lambda>() must be called with obj instance as first argument (got nothing instead)`